# Is there an iOS Camera App that shoots a photo every minute?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, camera

I would like to have an App that shoots a picture every minute, so I can carry my iPhone in my breast pocket to have a photoblog of my day.

A perfect solution would be if that app could create a video from those photos directly.

Comment: Why not just take a video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at stop motion apps, like [Stop Motion Recorder](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stopmotion-recorder/id373313019?mt=8), [StopAnimator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stop-animator/id494803047?mt=8), [Frameographer - Stop Motion & Time-Lapse](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id503347879?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4), [iMotion HD](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/imotion-hd/id421365625?mt=8) and so on.

You can get a variety of apps if you search for "stop motion" in the app store.

Comment: that was the searchquery i was looking for, thx